# From Qt Designer to Qgis

Tags: python, qt, qgis, osgeo

I'm starting to work with PyQgis. However, I have been stuck at one point for some time.

1. I have designed a basic dialog box to do integration tests in Qgis, called Test.ui
2. This file has been compiled with the use of OSGEO4w Shell obtaining a Test.py module.
3. In QGis I open the Python console to apply this dialog box designed to a script with a functionality. This Python script in Qgis declares a line qid = QInputDialog ().

This is where I stopped, since I do not know how to apply the design in Qt Designer in the Python console script in QGis.
What path should the compiled * .py modules follow?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting to learn language, reading your question I suggest that you see the creation of plugins in python, the standard example of exporting data from shape to a csv, already shows how to connect a .ui screen to a python script, which is your intention .

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html

Comment: Hi. thanks for the great reference. I will read it carefully.